# como agregar un valor a un atributo de un objeto en js?

Tags: javascript

Por ejemplo, tengo

```
equipo={ 'nombre':..., 'socios': socio 1,...}
```

como agrego otro socio al atributo `'socios'` del objeto equipo?

gracias

Comment: Para lo que deseas tu atributo socios debe ser un arreglo, ya sea de string u objetos dependiendo lo que necesites

Answer (score 2):

Te dejo un script que hace lo que requieres, la explicación en el codigo.

```js
equipo={'nombre':'Nombre', 'socios': ['socio 1']}
console.log('Solo con un socio ',equipo)

// Agrego socio 2, con la funcion push para el array dentro del atributo socios del objeto equipo
equipo.socios.push('socio 2')
console.log('Ahora con el socio 2 ', equipo);
```

Ejemplo y [documentacion](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/push)

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que un push bastará:

```
equipo['socios'].push(otroSocio);
```

Puedes revisar más sobre esta función en [este](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) y otros links.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas que socios sea un arreglo, para que puedas agregar mas de uno a través de la funcion `push`:

```js
let equipo = {
  nombre: "Nombre del equipo",
  socios: [
    "Socio 1",
    "Socio 2",
    "Socio 3"
  ]
}

//Si quieres agregar otro socio

equipo.socios.push("Socio 4");

//O también
equipo["socios"].push("Socio 5");

console.log(equipo)
```